# Undefined index: while saving user inputted data in text fields on form submit

Tags: php, forms, session, post

When `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is turned on I'm having the following example of notice

```
Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/test.php on line 111
Notice:  Undefined index: identity in /home/user/public_html/directory/subdirectory/test.php on line 116
```

in every form field if I want to save user inputted data in text fields using `session` after the form is submitted by the users.

Example of my current code is as following:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['identity'], "text")

  <?php  $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST; ?>

  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="userform" id="userform">
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?= $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>" size="25" />
  <input name="identity" type="text" id="identity" value="<?= $_SESSION['form']['identity']; ?>" size="25" />

and so on.............
```

Any idea?

Comment: post full error message please

Comment: have you started your session??

Comment: @ user3091574 yes session was started.

Comment: @Aaroniker , I edited my question indicating full notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['form']['name'];` and `$_SESSION['form']['identity'];` are undefined

set them to fix the warning:

```
$_SESSION['form']['name'] = '';
$_SESSION['form']['identity'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all **identity** is undefined
if you are gonna change **indentity** to **identity1**(or something else) then it works perfectly
for displaying you have to use **echo**

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="userform" id="userform">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['name']; ?>"    size="25" />
 <input name="identity1" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['identity1']; ?>" size="25" />
```

other then that every thing is fine

Comment: It was a mistake of my subconscious mind about a very common and basic issue when I was  replacing the code . I edited my question. Thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond you just have to change **identity** field to somthing else like **identity1**

Comment: what's the deal with that? can't we use whatever unique field name we want?

Comment: I didn't try that as your suggestion looks illogical & irrelevant to me. I accepted the answer that was given by Aaroniker

Answer (score 0):

Side note: you gave your inputs the same name.

```
<input name="name">
<input name="name">
```

If your users submit this, you won't have an "identity" field in your $_POST array.

However, **NOTICE** -s are not really important.  They notify you about something that *might be* a problem but if you want to avoid this kind of notice you'd have to check every array element before you refer to it - which is a lot of extra work for nothing.  So this time you can forget about your notices, they only warn you for this:

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['identity'], "text")
```

...because the first time POST won't have any of the fields. This is natural. You should count on empty values but it's not a problem to have empty values.  There are lots of situations where you'll be accessing nonexistent array elements and it's FINE.

Notice is like your mother warning you that it's cold out there.

Comment: It was a mistake of my subconscious mind about a very common and basic issue when I was replacing the code . I edited my question. Thanks,